# how to setup XP as wifi router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

i have a wired connection and a wireless card on xp dell laptop. how can i convert my laptop into a wifi router so that others can use my internet through wireless.

[I have been following the instructions from Lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/280002/turn-your-laptop-into-a-wireless-hot-spot)

However i cannot share my local area connection it gives error stating that i have to set the connections to share and local area connections is not on that dropdown.

Comment: Router would be the wrong term, "Internet connection sharing" would be. You can edit your post to rephrase the question.

Answer (score 0):

I have been following the instructions under
http://lifehacker.com/280002/turn-your-laptop-into-a-wireless-hot-spot

However i cannot share my local area connection it gives error stating that i have to set the connections to share and local area connections is not on that dropdown.

Comment: here is the link for my local area connections. http://d.pr/RwXY